# Sort array of array dynamically based on propery value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have JSON which Each records attributes has seperate object, I want to sort by attributes dynamically.

I am manage to do dthe sorting with attributes, but it's static code. How Could I make it dynamically ?

Please find running code on : https://jsfiddle.net/b8fv4L1z/3/

```
var json = [
  [
    {
      "apiName": "Name",
      "value": "Bob"
      },
    {
      "apiName": "CompanyName",
      "value": "Google"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "apiName": "Name",
      "value": "Micky"
    },
    {
      "apiName": "CompanyName",
      "value": "Amazon"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "apiName": "Name",
      "value": "Donal"
    },
    {
      "apiName": "CompanyName",
      "value": "Facebook"
    }
  ]
];


 function Comparator(a, b, ) {

   if (a[1].value < b[1].value) return -1; // a[1] sort by CompanyName If I put a[0] it will sort by Name.
   if (a[1].value > b[1].value) return 1; // a[1] sort by CompanyName If I put a[0] it will sort by Name.
   return 0;
 }

json = json.sort(Comparator);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Expected Result:

(Sorted by apiName = CompanyName):

```
 [[{"apiName":"Name","value":"Micky"},{"apiName":"CompanyName","value":"Amazon"}],[{"apiName":"Name","value":"Donal"},{"apiName":"CompanyName","value":"Facebook"}],[{"apiName":"Name","value":"Bob"},{"apiName":"CompanyName","value":"Google"}]]
```

(Sorted by apiName = Name):

```
     [[{"apiName":"Name","value":"Bob"},{"apiName":"CompanyName","value":"Google"}],[{"apiName":"Name","value":"Donal"},{"apiName":"CompanyName","value":"Facebook"}],[{"apiName":"Name","value":"Micky"},{"apiName":"CompanyName","value":"Amazon"}]]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. what is the rule for sorting by `name`? you have nested arrays. on which array shoulf the sorting happen?

Comment: As, I have update. Expected result should be short by attributs. 
I can manage to do the sort by static value. I want to make it dynamic. 
Currently I have two attributes (Name & CompanyName)  in future I have multiple attributs. How I can make it dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

With comparator made higher-order function.

```js
var json = [
  [{
      "apiName": "Name",
      "value": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "apiName": "CompanyName",
      "value": "Google"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "apiName": "Name",
      "value": "Micky"
    },
    {
      "apiName": "CompanyName",
      "value": "Amazon"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "apiName": "Name",
      "value": "Donal"
    },
    {
      "apiName": "CompanyName",
      "value": "Facebook"
    }
  ]
];

function findValueByProperty(item, propertyName) {
  var relevantRow = item.find(function(content) {
    return content.apiName === propertyName;
  });
  return relevantRow.value;
}

function comparator(propertyName) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var valueA = findValueByProperty(a, propertyName);
    var valueB = findValueByProperty(b, propertyName);
    return valueA.localeCompare(valueB)
  }
}

console.log('json==>' + JSON.stringify(json));
console.log(json.slice().sort(comparator("CompanyName")));
console.log(json.slice().sort(comparator("Name")));
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I get only propertt name. How I can find the index for the same ? 
e.g: sort by Name or CompanyName or somet other value (which index not be deceded)

Comment: Edited to execute lookup property name.

Comment: Both my original answer and Piyush's comment predate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could find the wanted property. Maybe you need a default value, like an empty string.

```js
function sort(array, apiName) {
    const
        getValue = array => 
            (array.find(o => o.apiName === apiName) || { value: '' }).value;

    return array.sort((a, b) => getValue(a).localeCompare(getValue(b)));
}

var array = [[{ apiName: "Name", value: "Bob" }, { apiName: "CompanyName", value: "Google" }], [{ apiName: "Name", value: "Micky" }, { apiName: "CompanyName", value: "Amazon" }], [{ apiName: "Name", value: "Donal" }, { apiName: "CompanyName", value: "Facebook" }]];

console.log(sort(array, 'CompanyName'));
console.log(sort(array, 'Name'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have always the same data structure, you could get the `apiName` in advance and sort without a finding for every element.

```js
function sort(array, apiName) {
    const index = array[0].findIndex(o => o.apiName === apiName);

    return array.sort((a, b) => a[index].value.localeCompare(b[index].value));
}

var array = [[{ apiName: "Name", value: "Bob" }, { apiName: "CompanyName", value: "Google" }], [{ apiName: "Name", value: "Micky" }, { apiName: "CompanyName", value: "Amazon" }], [{ apiName: "Name", value: "Donal" }, { apiName: "CompanyName", value: "Facebook" }]];

console.log(sort(array, 'CompanyName'));
console.log(sort(array, 'Name'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```